# Windows 2008 R2 64 bit + ColdFusion 8 + 64 Bit JVM - Error loading: C:/ColdFusion8/runtime/jre\bin\server\jvm.dll

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, jvm-crash

We have ColdFusion 8 running on Windows 2003 and JVM 1.6 Build 17 and they work without any issues. We are trying to upgrade to Windows 2008 R2 and when we point ColdFusion 8 to the 64 bit JVM 1.6_17, we get this error in ColdFusion out logs.

```
Error loading: C:/ColdFusion8/runtime/jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

We figured out `msvcr71.dll` has been missing and copied it to the `C:\ColdFusion8\runtime\bin` directory, but nothing seems to be changing.

In the Windows event viewer I can see this message ***The ColdFusion 8 Application Server service terminated with service-specific error The system cannot find the file specified..***

It looks that `JVM.DLL` has some more dependencies dlls, which are missing on the file system. How can we get the dependencies the `jvm.dll` has been looking for? Or can we know which specified file its not able to find?

Comment: Are you running ColdFusion 8 Update 1?  I believe that was the first version to support 64 bit JVM.  Since you are upgrading OS versions why not upgrade ColdFusion as well?  I realize that ColdFusion 10 is very different from ColdFusion 8 but ColdFusion 9 is very similar. You should at least upgrade to ColdFusion 9 (in my opinion).

Comment: Also, are you installing the 64 bit version of ColdFusion 8 Update 1?

Comment: Just to be sure, does that DLL actually exist? You may need to use the JDK if you're using the JRE.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue. I installed the 64 bit version of Microsoft Visual C++ redistributional version 2010. ColdFusion started fine after that.